# Why did stopping Vosk from returning to the future reset the timeline (including the past)

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-enterprise, timeline

In the Enterprise season 4 episodes Storm Front 1 & 2, the ship ends up in an alternative timeline where the Germans overran England and invaded the East coast of the US during WWII.  (These events occurred prior to Enterprise arriving.)

Daniels tells Archer that he needs to stop the Na'Kuhl Vosk from using his time conduit and returning to the future.  The Enterprise destroys the conduit just as Vosk enters it.  This causes the timeline to completely reset, including erasing the differences that had already occurred in the past (including the assassination of Lenin in 1918 which was the key event that precipitated the success of the Germans).

So:

1. Why/How did getting rid of Vosk reset the timeline?
2. How did it reset things that already happened in the past?
3. Who was the shadowy figure who assassinated Lenin in 1918, (and then disappeared into thin air)?

---

Note to people who will invariably answer with "Timey wimey".  Please note that although I have been watching Dr Who since before Jon Pertwee, I absolutely detest that phrase and it totally grinds my gears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your first and second questions would appear to lie in what Daniels said to Archer near the end of the first part of [Storm Front](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Storm_Front_(episode))...

> **ARCHER:** "Who were they?"
>
> **DANIELS:** "The most dangerous faction of the Cold War. They're led by Vosk, a fanatic, violently opposed to the Temporal Accords."
>
> **ARCHER:** "Stay with me. Stay with me."
>
> **DANIELS:** "We almost captured him, but he developed a form of stealth time travel. He escaped into the past. We eventually located him, but it was too late. He returned to my century. He and his people defeated us and launched this war that's destroying all of time. I've sent you to this point because it's here that Vosk can be stopped. If you succeed, the war will never happen. The timeline will be restored."
>
> **ARCHER:** "One of his people told me they were building a conduit."
>
> **DANIELS:** "Vosk's time travel device had a drawback. It was a one-way trip. He needed to construct the conduit to get home, but he was forced to use technology from this time period. The machine would have to be enormous. Find it. Destroy it. He must not succeed. Stop him."

According to his, if Vosk had succeeded in returning to the future in [Storm Front, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Storm_Front,_Part_II_(episode)), he would've escalated the [Temporal Cold War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_Cold_War) into a full-scale [Temporal War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_War), resulting in multiple temporal incursions, one of which created the alternate version of WW2 we saw in those episodes. Killing Vosk before he could return to his own time prevented the war escalating, and all the temporal incursions that followed.

As to the identity of Lenin's assassin, I don't believe that was ever revealed. The only clue/s we have as to who that assassin *might* have been working for lie in the following conversation from *Storm Front, Part II*...

> **REED:** "I think I've pinpointed where the timeline changed. Someone assassinated Lenin in 1916."
>
> **ARCHER:** "Who took his place?"
>
> **REED:** "No one. So without Lenin, the Bolsheviks never gained power. Russia didn't become Communist, and Germany never considered it a threat."
>
> **ARCHER:** "Hitler was able to concentrate on the West."
>
> **REED:** "After France, Belgium and the Netherlands fell. Hitler quickly took England and then the eastern United States."
>
> **T'POL:** "But Vosk and his men arrived on Earth recently. A few years ago."
>
> **ARCHER:** "Then they couldn't have been responsible for the changes that took place in 1916."
>
> **REED:** "The police never captured Lenin's assassin. Some bystanders claimed that the killer vanished into thin air."
>
> **T'POL:** "Daniels said that different factions in the Temporal War are changing history throughout the timeline. Maybe this assassin was working for one of them."
>
> **REED:** "But I thought we were here to prevent Vosk from starting the temporal war."
>
> **ARCHER:** "Chicken or the egg."

So according to this, the killer was not a member of Vosk's faction, the Na'kuhl, and was presumably working for one of the other factions involved in the Temporal War. As to *which* other faction, the claim that the killer "vanished into thin air" seems like a possible hint that the killer was Suliban, but we'll never know for sure.

Comment: OK .. so temporal paradox of Archer not stopping Vosk causes hot war which changes timeline, but Archer exists  because he stopped Vosk thus headed off hot war.  As for the  assassin, "vanished into thin air" has multiple in-universe meanings.  It could be Suliban style camouflage,  or it could be transported mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

The temporal cold war never made any sense.

That being said there really is no answer to your question in canon, it is simply never expounded upon, Daniels merely says "the timeline is resetting itself" and gives no other explanation.

I would assume destroying the conduit created some kind of wave that resonated through space and time, altering any object that lacked temporal shielding, but that is merely speculation.

As to who the figure was again no canon answer beyond an agent for a faction of the temporal cold war probably an agent of Vosk's faction but not necessarily.

Comment: I don't think that time travel itself ever made sense in this series.  EG how did Daniels escape the post-apocalyptic future that he and Archer ended up in, after only Archer was sent back in time?